# Why isn't the perl regex being as greedy as I need it to be?

Tags: regex, string, regex-greedy, perl

So present this string:

```
!NAME: "Slot 10 SubSlot 0"
```

There may be some stuff after the final quote mark, but that is irrelevant to the task at hand.

The goal is, I want to capture everything after Slot UP UNTIL the final quote mark.

I have tried two regexes for the task

```
/^!NAME:\s+\".*(Slot[\w|\s|\d+]+)\"/;
```

The other:

```
/^!NAME:\s+\".*(Slot.+)\"/;
```

But these only capture

```
Slot 0
```

What comes after Slot can be wildly different.  It could be anything like:

```
'Slot 4' (this works, but the capture string will not always be this small)

'Slot 4 Subslot 12 Internal Subslot 14 External'

'Slot 75 Internal Slot 12 External'
```

The only thing that we know for certain is that the section we want will begin with 'Slot', and will end with a quotation mark.  Anything else in between is up in the air.

What is wrong with what I have shown?  Especially the second one, as I thought that the '.' operator was greedy and would capture as much as it can?

The purpose of this script is to capture these details to be parsed in another program.

Comment: Because `.*` is greedy, so the "Slot" you get is the last one. Test your pattern with regex101.com  and use the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Why are you escaping the double-quotes? That is not needed in a Perl regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being greedy.

```
/^!NAME:\s+\".*(Slot[\w|\s|\d+]+)\"/;
             ^^
              |----- The greedy part is here.
```

Since your target string matches `Slot \d+` in two places, the `.*` after the quote slurps up the first one. Try making that part of the expression non-greedy:

```
/!NAME:\s+\".*?(Slot(?:\w|\s|\d+)+)\"/
```

Comment: `(?:\w|\s|\d+)+`? `[\w\s\d]+`!

Comment: I strongly recommend against using non-greediness as anything but an optimization. Consider how your solution handles `!NAME: "Slot 4 x! SubSlot 14 External"`. Rather than rejecting the match, it sees `Slot 14 External`

Answer (score 1):

This should capture everything that's not a quote that comes after Slot but before the quote:

```
/^!NAME:\s+\"Slot([^\"]*)\"/
```

And to include the Slot part if you need it for some reason

```
/^!NAME:\s+\"(Slot[^\"]*)\"/
```

Comment: This won't capture the initial `Slot`, only what comes after.

Comment: Yeah, that's what he said he wanted on the 4th line of the question *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

The safest answer:

```
/^ !NAME: \s* " (?:(?!Slot).)* Slot ( [^"]* ) "/x
```

You could also make sure that `Slot` is not part of another word:

```
/^ !NAME: \s* " (?:(?!Slot).)* \b Slot \b ( [^"]* ) "/x
```

The trick is knowing that `(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

Comment: The sample data doesn't have double quotes, but I think this is the best answer either way.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, The only complete example text does have a double-quote. Additionally, the explanation says to match until a quote, and the OP's attempt includes a double-quote.

Answer (score 0):

This works with all your example text:

```
^!NAME:\s*"(Slot.*?)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/hB1cT3/2

NB: All your examples contain nothing in quotes except the "Slot" text, so why are you putting in a `.*` as the first thing in the quotes? As mentioned above by mob, this was what was causing problems. I've removed it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
/(Slot[^"]+)/
```

Here it is in action:

```
my $s = '!NAME: "Slot 10 SubSlot 0"';
$s =~ /(Slot[^"]+)/;
print $1;

# Slot 10 SubSlot 0
```

If you need to specify that the line begins with `!NAME:`, then just expand it to this:

```
/^!NAME:\s"(Slot[^"]+)/
```